# Edit this code to run through all CSV files in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to preface this with the fact that I am brand new to python and pandas.  I created the code below to run through the CSV file and parse out rows based on column value, then create and save into 5 CSVs. The challenge I am facing now is that I have 50 files.  I am hoping to find a way that I can use what I have and then add a loop that will run through the entire folder; instead of entering the path of each file individually.  Thanks for any help possible.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21.csv",)
df=df.rename(columns = {'Segmentation/Pool Code':'Code'})

df_Auto = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(['21', '94', '103', '105', '22', '82', '97', '104', '1', '71', '100', '2', '35', '62', '72', '101'])]

df_Mortgage = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["M000","M001", "M003", "M004", "M005", "M006", "M007", "M008","M010", "M011", "M013", "M014", "M015", "M016", "M024", "M025", "M027", "M028", "M029", "M031", "M033", "M035","M036","M037","M038","M039",'M040','M041','M042','M043','M044','M020','M021','M022','M023','M026','M032','M034', '18', '28', '34', '87'])]

df_HELOC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["17","83","88","19","31","84","85"])]

df_CC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["116","118","119","120","121","122","123","125"])]

df_Other = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["33","41","51","52", "56","57","58","59","75","76","130","131","132","133","134","135","136","140","54", "55","60","77", "78","79","115","4","5","6","7","13","14","16", "32","44","45","46","47","67","106","107","109","110","160","3","10","11","12","25","69","95","102"])]

#Save Files
df_Auto.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21_auto.csv")
df_Mortgage.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21_Mortgafe.csv")
df_HELOC.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21_HELOC.csv")
df_CC.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21_CC.csv")
df_Other.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Kris\Data\Loans 12-21.csv")
```

Comment: perhaps look into the os library? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: I think each `to_csv` call you have there will overwrite the previous file, right?

Comment: first create function which get path and runs all for one file and later use for-loop to run it with list which have different files. And you can use `os.listdir()`, `os.walk()` or `glob.glob()` to create list with files in some directory. This problem was many times on Stackoverflow and today I already saw one similar question

Comment: @richardec you're right, I corrected it.

Comment: @furas I have read multiple pages and quite a few posts before posting. Like I said I have little to no experience in python. I tried os.listdir() and was getting errors. I set up a glob.glob() and it ran and saved all the separate files but didn't have any rows in the files except for mortgage.  That is why I am reaching out for assistance.

Comment: first you should say in question that you already tried `os.listdir(), os.walk() or glob.glob()`. And if you get error then you should show it in question - and we could explain what you made wrong. It can be more usefule then writing example similar to other answers.

Comment: Here is the error I am receiving when trying to use os.listdir. "File "c:\Users\kris\OneDrive\Training\Python\loop", line 7 url = "C:\Users\Kris\OneDrive\10b\DFAST\Data" ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

When I used glob.glob() - everything ran and the mortgage file had all the correct data but the other 4 files were blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a starting point. It will read each CSV in the `csvs` list, process it, and write the results to several new files:

```
import pandas as pd 
import os

csv_dir = r"C:\Users\Kris\Data"
csvs = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(csv_dir) if entry.name.lower().endswith('.csv')]

for csv in csvs:
    df=pd.read_csv(csv)
    df=df.rename(columns = {'Segmentation/Pool Code':'Code'})

    df_Auto = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(['21', '94', '103', '105', '22', '82', '97', '104', '1', '71', '100', '2', '35', '62', '72', '101'])]

    df_Mortgage = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["M000","M001", "M003", "M004", "M005", "M006", "M007", "M008","M010", "M011", "M013", "M014", "M015", "M016", "M024", "M025", "M027", "M028", "M029", "M031", "M033", "M035","M036","M037","M038","M039",'M040','M041','M042','M043','M044','M020','M021','M022','M023','M026','M032','M034', '18', '28', '34', '87'])]

    df_HELOC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["17","83","88","19","31","84","85"])]

    df_CC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["116","118","119","120","121","122","123","125"])]

    df_Other = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["33","41","51","52", "56","57","58","59","75","76","130","131","132","133","134","135","136","140","54", "55","60","77", "78","79","115","4","5","6","7","13","14","16", "32","44","45","46","47","67","106","107","109","110","160","3","10","11","12","25","69","95","102"])]

    #Save Files
    file_name, ext = os.path.splitext(csv)
    df_Auto.to_csv(f"{file_name}_auto{ext}")
    df_Mortgage.to_csv(f"{file_name}_Mortgafe{ext}")
    df_HELOC.to_csv(f"{file_name}_HELOC{ext}")
    df_CC.to_csv(f"{file_name}_CC{ext}")
    df_Other.to_csv(f"{file_name}{ext}")
```

Comment: Thank you for that help! Does pointing it at a folder and having it run through the entire folder require a lot more work? Only reason I ask is because the next batch I will need to process is going to be 12 years worth of month files.

Comment: I updated it to find the CSV files from a folder. Check it now :)

Comment: Awesome thank you! So I am running into the same issue I was getting when I tried using glob.glob.  It is creating all the files but only the mortgage files have rows in them.  I copied over the dataframe for each category from my original file which did generate rows in all 5 files.  Any idea why this would be?  I am getting a low_memory warning and dtype error, but I was getting those with the original code as well.

Comment: The low_memory warning doesn't sound like a problem, but the dtype error sounds like it might be one. What is is? Also, could the reason only the mortgage one is being populated be a problem with your logic?

Comment: There isn't enough room to copy and paste all of the errors but there is one of these for each file.  I was getting the same errors when doing the one file and it worked okay.  The logic should be good, I just reran the original and it is pulling all the correct info in. 


c:\Users\Kris\Training\Python\loop5.py:8: DtypeWarning: Columns (4,11,12,38,43,45,50,59,64,66) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  df=pd.read_csv(csv)

Comment: So column 4 is the column of "code" so perhaps it is causing an issue now.

Comment: In fact, one of the files isnt even giving an error in that column and it still isnt working. Any type of advise or where to turn for research would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

when folder have only csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

url = "C://Users//Kris//Data//" # insert your csv folder path
files = os.listdir(url)

for i in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(url + i)
    df=df.rename(columns = {'Segmentation/Pool Code':'Code'})

    df_Auto = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(['21', '94', '103', '105', '22', '82', '97', '104', '1', '71', '100', '2', '35', '62', '72', '101'])]

    df_Mortgage = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["M000","M001", "M003", "M004", "M005", "M006", "M007", "M008","M010", "M011", "M013", "M014", "M015", "M016", "M024", "M025", "M027", "M028", "M029", "M031", "M033", "M035","M036","M037","M038","M039",'M040','M041','M042','M043','M044','M020','M021','M022','M023','M026','M032','M034', '18', '28', '34', '87'])]

    df_HELOC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["17","83","88","19","31","84","85"])]

    df_CC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["116","118","119","120","121","122","123","125"])]

    df_Other = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["33","41","51","52", "56","57","58","59","75","76","130","131","132","133","134","135","136","140","54", "55","60","77", "78","79","115","4","5","6","7","13","14","16", "32","44","45","46","47","67","106","107","109","110","160","3","10","11","12","25","69","95","102"])]

    #Save Files

    df_Auto.to_csv(url + i[:-4] + "_auto.csv")
    df_Mortgage.to_csv(url + i[:-4] + "_Mortgafe.csv")
    df_HELOC.to_csv(url + i[:-4] + "_HELOC.csv")
    df_CC.to_csv(url + i[:-4] + "_CC.csv")
    df_Other.to_csv(url + i[:-4] +".csv")
```

Comment: I am getting this error.   Should it be i isnt of csv? Sorry I am very new. 

df=pd.read_csv(csv)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: sorry replace csv to url + i . i repair my answer

Comment: then change i.split(".")[0] to i[:-4]. i change my answer 1more

Comment: Above I asked why the rows aren't pulling over.  The column does have a mix of letters and numbers but I didnt have any issues with my first file.  Any idea what could be the problem here?